# Two way databinding with Linq to SQL in a WPF textbox or other control

Tags: wpf, linq, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a two way databind using a WPF textbox control to the results of a linq query.  I wrote an application to test this, but although the last row from my table shows up on the initial load, once I add a new row the new value isn't updated in my textbox.  My code:

XAML-Code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2Test6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbTest" BorderBrush="#FFCB5D5D" Width="50" Height="25" Text="{Binding Source=valueP, Path=ProcessID, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C# CodeBehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication2Test6
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Window1_Loaded);  
        }

        void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BindingList<ProcessUpdate> processList = new BindingList<ProcessUpdate>();
            var processID = ProcessUpdate.GetNewProcessValue().ProcessID;
            tbTest.Text = processID.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class ProcessUpdate : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int pid;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

         private ProcessUpdate()
        {
            WpfApplication2Test6.MonthlyBudgetEntities entity = new MonthlyBudgetEntities();

            var valueP = (from p in entity.WPFTestTables
                          select new { p.ProcessID }).ToList().Last();

            pid = valueP.ProcessID;

        }

        public static ProcessUpdate GetNewProcessValue()
        {
            return new ProcessUpdate();
        }

        public int ProcessID
        {
            get { return pid; }
            set
            {
                pid = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ProcessID");
            }
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string pid)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pid.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Too broad. If you have a specific problem with a specific part of your code, then post the relevant code and XAML, please.

Comment: You bind to a *view model*, not to the actual data source: whether you're using L2S or EF is just how you get data into your viewmodel. And yes, that's quite a broad question.

Comment: Rob T, the idea of this site is to ask questions that have a specific answer, rather than questions that seek general advice (and therefore don't really have a "right answer"). If you get started with your project and come across something in particular need help with, please definitely search StackOverflow, and if you don't find what you're looking for, ask another question.

Comment: I edited my question and posted my code after my question was put on hold, now it's closed.  What did I miss?

Comment: I edited my question and posted my code after my question was put on hold, now it's closed. What did I miss?

Comment: I edited my question and posted my code after my question was put on hold, now it's closed. What did I miss?

Comment: I edited my question and posted my code after my question was put on hold, now it's closed. What did I miss?

Comment: The value you are binding to; are you calling the PropertyChanged event for it, when the underlaying value is changed?

Comment: I couldn't get my question past the forum nazis here, so I took it to the MSDN forums.  They are a little more forgiving there and took the time to understand the intent of my question, instead of how correctly I phrased it.  From what I can tell the "power users" on StackExchange seem more interested in generating digital points next to their avatars than actually helping.  I won't be coming back, so go ahead and flame me for my perceptions of how newbies are treated here.